# Why does it take so much time to execute semodule -i mypol.pp?

Tags: selinux

Command `semodule -i mypol.pp` takes more than one minute to execute. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing the policy file, one can only guess, but it's probably because the policy is somewhat far-reaching in what it affects. Policies amount to changes to the filesystem, labeling the affected files. So, if your policy names a broad swath of the filesystem as being under its control, all of those files have to have their metadata modified.

Comment: A simple example is a trivial small policy file that just allows processes labeled `collect_t` to read files labeled `var_log_t` (i.e. one allow rule) - under RHEL/CentOS 7. Even on relatively recent hardware (including SSD) it takes like a minute or longer to load.